# C# Linq datetime to string "dd/mm/yyyy"

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, sql-function

I want to convert a datetime into a string with format `"dd/mm/yyyy"` inside an entity framework linq query.

I tried to use SqlFunctions. This does not give me the right format `("d/m/yyy")`

I don't want to write a query and then do a .toList() method and then convert the datetime to string with the `.ToString("dd/mm/yyyy")` method.

Are there other ways to try or am I missing something with SqlFunctions?

```
db.table.Select(i => new Data() {
     stringDate = SqlFunctions.DateName("dd", i.databaseData) + "/" +
               SqlFunctions.DatePart("m", i.databaseData) + "/" +
               SqlFunctions.DatePart("year", i.databaseData),
}).ToList()
```

EDIT:

Executing below query with a the Stopwacht function System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.StartNew() takes 10x more time to execute than previous query

```
db.table.AsEnumerable().Select(i => new Data() {
    stringDate = String.Format("{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", i.databaseData),
}
```

Comment: "I don't want to write a query and then do a .toList() method and then convert the datetime to string with the .toString("dd/mm/yyyy") method." - well you don't have to materialize the result, but is there any particular reason you want to do the formatting within the database rather than locally?

Comment: Where are you trying to use this date? Is it being displayed on a UI?

Comment: What's wrong with `ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")`? (other than that you seem to have tried using the minutes `mm`)

Comment: `SqlFunctions` does not expose T-SQL's `FORMAT` or `CONVERT` (with the third parameter), but then that is unnecessary, because `FORMAT` uses the .NET logic in the first place! There is no compelling use case for making the database format values in a way that can be done just as well *and* better by the client side, which is why `SqlFunctions` does not bother exposing any of that. If text values have found their way into the database that should have been `DATETIME`s, and the conversion has to be server-side for performance, a computed column sounds like a better alternative.

Comment: Because it's faster to immediatly select the correct format rather than doing a select statement followed up with another select statement just to convert the date to a string. It is needed to send this data to an angular application

Comment: "Faster", did you actually verify this?

Comment: ToSting method does not working within EF linq, only after using toList(). And I want to avoid to use this (if there are other possibilities of course)

Comment: Highly doubtful. Transferring `DATETIME` values as bytes to the client and then formatting those into a string on the client side is generally faster than having the engine produce a string and transferring that (because, for starters, that takes more I/O). This is not the kind of calculation that speeds up by farming it out to the server. You do *not* need to call `.ToList()` to materialize the results first -- `.AsEnumerable()` to switch to LINQ to Objects will do.

Comment: Carefull with micro optimisation. "it's faster to immediatly select the correct format rather". I doubt you can see the difference even on billon row.

Comment: @pelvimet What makes you think 3 conversion function calls plus concatenating the results are faster than 1 `ToString()`?

Comment: why not doing it after the ToList()? or in the frontEnd?

Comment: The difference between execution time of  the two methods are indeed very small even for large amount of data. But that's not my question. My question is if their are other ways of implementing the SqlFunctions withouth using .ToString("dd/mm/yyyy")

Comment: Sure. The existing `SqlFunction`s work by having a custom attribute that the query provider reflects over when constructing the query. Extending EF to respect something like that for a custom function that exposes `CONVERT`/`FORMAT` is possible. It's just quite a bit of work that nobody should have any real incentive to do, though -- at least not for *this* use case.

Comment: If this is just for display purposes, surely you can get your angular app to handle this? After all, if it's only for display then logically this sits as the responsibility of the display / UI layer. Perhaps use the DatePipe: https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe

Comment: What is wrong with the `SqlFunctions` version? You have multiple formats showing that aren't clear. Time `db.table.Select(i => i.databaseData).AsEnumerable().Select(d => new Data() { stringDate = String.Format("{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", d) }`.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming what you meant was you want the final result to be `dd/mm/yyyy` then you can construct this manually.

Using a trick with VisualBasic's `Right` function makes it easy:

```
var ans = db.table.Select(i => new Data() {
     stringDate = Microsoft.VisualBasic.Strings.Right("0"+SqlFunctions.DatePart("d", i.databaseData), 2) + "/" +
               Microsoft.VisualBasic.Strings.Right("0"+SqlFunctions.DatePart("m", i.databaseData), 2) + "/" +
               Microsoft.VisualBasic.Strings.Right("000"+SqlFunctions.DatePart("year", i.databaseData), 2),
}).ToList();
```

To stick to C#, you must repeat the expressions:

```
var ans2 = db.table.Select(i => new Data() {
     stringDate = (SqlFunctions.DatePart("d", i.databaseData).ToString().Length == 1 ? "0"+SqlFunctions.DatePart("d", i.databaseData) : SqlFunctions.DatePart("d", i.databaseData).ToString()) + "/" +
               (SqlFunctions.DatePart("m", i.databaseData).ToString().Length == 1 ? "0"+SqlFunctions.DatePart("d", i.databaseData) : SqlFunctions.DatePart("d", i.databaseData).ToString()) + "/" +
               ("000"+SqlFunctions.DatePart("year", i.databaseData)).Substring(SqlFunctions.DatePart("year", i.databaseData).ToString().Length-1),
}).ToList();
```